# How to deserialize a json dictionary into a custom type

Tags: c#, json

I have a type and a JSON string that can be serialized into this type out of the box:

```
public class MyVar
{
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public class TypeA
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, MyVar> Vars { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to deserialize the same JSON string into a custom type that wraps the dictionary?

```
public class MyVars
{
    private IDictionary<string, MyVar> _vars;

    public MyVar this[string key]
    {
        get { ... }
        set { ... }
    }
    ...
}

public class TypeA
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public MyVars Vars { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you just use the documentation? http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyVars>(output);

Comment: It wont be the same Json string as you've introduced a new wrapping class. Run it through the serializer to see the new json string...

Comment: Wouldn't it suffice that you replace within `TypeA` the property with `public MyVars Vars { get; set;}` and that your `MyVars`implements `IDictionary<string, MyVar>`?

Comment: That's the question: The JSON deserializer is somehow able to create a dictionary out of a 'sub-string' in the whole content string. How to tell him not to create a dictionary in this place but rather a MyVars object? And what MyVars need to implement?

Comment: Create an example in code and let it serialize to json string. The result will look like your future json should look like, so dseserializer will deserialize it correctly.
Otherwise i recommend to use your own DTO and a mapper-class which converts your TypeA into whatever your business logic layer should work with (f.e. MyVars etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. I have to use a JsonConverter attribute.

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(MyVarsConverter))]
public MyVars Vars { get; set; }
```

And the implementation of the converter has to do the transformation from dictionary to an MyVars instance:

```
public class MyVarsConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var dictionary = serializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, MyVar>>(reader);
        var myVars = new MyVars(dictionary);
        return myVars;
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Jobject, extract the values using Jobject and set it to the property which you want to to.
For eg I have a Jobject jo

```
var name jo.GetValue("Name ").ToString();
```

You can loop through Jobject and extract and set value to your custom model.